Pre-Commit MyPy unable to disable non-error messages
I'm putting together some pre-commit hooks for a project that I'm working on, and one of the hooks we want to use is MyPy. The pre-commit results are throwing up a lot of non-error notes related to the "annotation-unchecked" flag, which I want to disable to de-clutter the command line output.
I have seen from a previous question Suppress Mypy notes that the solution would be to include a disable_error_code = ["annotation-unchecked"] in the pyproject.toml file, however, the notes still appear when running the pre-commit.
These are the current references to MyPy in the pyproject.toml file:
[tool.mypy]
mypy_path = "src"
disable_error_code = ["annotation-unchecked"]  # Disables non-error messages thrown up by mypy

And these are the settings from the pre-commit-config.yaml file:
# Type checking
- repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
  #rev: v0.910
  rev: v1.9.0
  hooks:
  - id: mypy
    files: '(src|tests)/.*\.py$'  # Single quote critical due to escape character '\' used in RegEx search string (see YAML - 7.3 Flow Scalar Styles)
    additional_dependencies: [types-requests]

These are the MyPy messages printed out in the command line. Note how the "notes" are still being printed despite the settings above.
src/pkg/file1.py:14: error: Argument 2 to "from_bytes" of "int" has incompatible type "str"; expected "Literal['little', 'big']"  [arg-type]
src/pkg/file1.py:21: error: Argument 2 to "from_bytes" of "int" has incompatible type "str"; expected "Literal['little', 'big']"  [arg-type]
src/pkg/file1.py:23: error: Argument 2 to "from_bytes" of "int" has incompatible type "str"; expected "Literal['little', 'big']"  [arg-type]
src/pkg/file2.py:60: note: By default the bodies of untyped functions are not checked, consider using --check-untyped-defs  [annotation-unchecked]
src/pkg/file3.py:143: note: By default the bodies of untyped functions are not checked, consider using --check-untyped-defs  [annotation-unchecked]
src/pkg/file4.py:125: note: By default the bodies of untyped functions are not checked, consider using --check-untyped-defs  [annotation-unchecked]
src/pkg/file4.py:126: note: By default the bodies of untyped functions are not checked, consider using --check-untyped-defs  [annotation-unchecked]
src/pkg/file5.py:20: note: By default the bodies of untyped functions are not checked, consider using --check-untyped-defs  [annotation-unchecked]
src/pkg/file5.py:21: note: By default the bodies of untyped functions are not checked, consider using --check-untyped-defs  [annotation-unchecked]
src/pkg/file6.py:75: note: By default the bodies of untyped functions are not checked, consider using --check-untyped-defs  [annotation-unchecked]
src/pkg/file7.py:164: note: By default the bodies of untyped functions are not checked, consider using --check-untyped-defs  [annotation-unchecked]
src/pkg/file8.py:709: error: Value of type "Coroutine[Any, Any, None]" must be used  [unused-coroutine]
src/pkg/file9.py:709: note: Are you missing an await?
src/pkg/file10.py:267: note: By default the bodies of untyped functions are not checked, consider using --check-untyped-defs  [annotation-unchecked]
Found 4 errors in 2 files (checked 72 source files)

Advice on what might have gone wrong here would be much appreciated, thanks!

It turns out this issue was caused by the presence of a .mypy.ini file in the project folder that I overlooked. Deleting it solved the problem.
When multiple configuration files are present in the project folder, MyPy looks for settings in the following order of priority (ref: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html):

./mypy.ini
./.mypy.ini
./pyproject.toml
./setup.cfg
$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mypy/config
~/.config/mypy/config
~/.mypy.ini

Where multiple such files exist, @anit3res' answer of adding an argument to the .pre-commit-config.yaml file specifying the config file to look at works beautifully:
- repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: v1.9.0
    hooks:
      - id: mypy
        files: '(src|tests)/.*\.py$'  # Single quote critical due to escape character '\' used in RegEx search string (see YAML - 7.3 Flow Scalar Styles)
        additional_dependencies: [types-requests]
        args: [--config-file=./pyproject.toml]


You have to pass your .pyproject.toml as config via the arguments of mypy, e.g.
- repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: v1.9.0
    hooks:
      - id: mypy
        files: '(src|tests)/.*\.py$'  # Single quote critical due to escape character '\' used in RegEx search string (see YAML - 7.3 Flow Scalar Styles)
        additional_dependencies: [types-requests]
        args: [--config-file=./pyproject.toml]


Thanks so much! Adding this argument worked.
I had a closer look at my project directory, and it looks like one of my collaborators included a minimally defined mypy.ini file from an earlier build that, from what I've read, takes precedence over the reading of pyproject.toml. After deleting that file, it works perfectly without the need for the argument now.

you shouldn't need this argument if you've configured mypy properly -- the actual problem is a different configuration file shadowing the one you expect

Thank you @anit3res, this is like the best answer and saved me a lot of time!
